# add category to a new task with react

Tags: reactjs

i want to add a category when i add a task

i try to add this with query selector the state is assigned but it don't appear no the new task

```
class AddTodo extends Component{
    state={
        content: '',
        importances:''

    }




    handleChange = (e, importances) => {
        var test=document.querySelector('select').value

        importances=test

        this.setState({
      content: e.target.value 
        })

    }
    handleSubmit = (e) =>  {
        e.preventDefault();


        this.props.addTodo(this.state)
        this.setState({content:''});

    }
        render(){

        return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> 
            <label>Add new Todo:</label>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.content}/>

            <select name="category" >
            <option value="Très important">Très important</option>
            <option value="Important">Important</option>
            <option value="A faire">A faire</option>
            </select>
            <button className="addBtn">Add</button>

            </form> 

        </div>

        )
    }
}
export default AddTodo
```

finaly i made this :
and add on the state by default property
selectedOption: 'Très important',

```
 <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> 
            <label>Add new Todo:</label>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.content} />
            <select value={current_option}  onChange={(e) => this.setState({ selectedOption: e.target.value })} >
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `onChange` event listener to the `select` component and handle the value of the select.

```
<select value={current_option} onChange={() => onOptionChanged()} >
```

Comment: Thanks i tried what you said and some other things and it worked